# Python: Fetching and parsing text from html files

Tags: python, html, parsing

I'm trying to work on a project about page ranking.

I want to make an index (dictionary) which looks like this: 
file1.html -> [[cat, ate, food, drank, milk], [file2.html, file3.html]] 
file2.html -> [[dog, barked, ran, away], [file1.html, file4.html]]

Fetching links is easy - look for anchor tags.

My question is - how do I fetch text? The text in the html files is not enclosed within any tags like `<p>`

Thanks in advance for all the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the text isn't enclosed in tags is it really HTML?
As Amber says, you'll have an easier job of this using some HTML parser like BeautifulSoup.

The example below demonstrates a simple method for returning text within tags.
This method works for any tag AFAIK.

```
>>> from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup as bs
>>> html = '''
... <div><a href="/link1">link1 contents</a></div>
... <div><a href="/link2">link2 contents</a></div>
... '''
>>> soup = bs(html)
>>> for anchor_tag in soup.findAll('a'):
...   print anchor_tag.contents[0]
... 
link1 contents
link2 contents
```

Apart from that I can imagine that you'd want a dictionary with a count of how many times a certain term appeared in some HTML document.  `defaultdict` is good for that kind of thing:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict(int)
>>> for anchor_tag in soup.findAll('a'):
...   d[anchor_tag.contents[0]] += 1
... 
>>> d
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {u'link1 contents': 1, u'link2 contents': 1})
```

Hopefully that gives you some ideas to run with.  Come back and open another question if you run into other issues.

Answer (score 1):

Use an HTML parser - something like [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/).

Comment: Yes, I'm using beautifulsoup, unfortunately, I'm unable to parse text thats not enclosed within any tags